# C# EF6 Core - call USP to modify tables without SaveChanges - what is the result?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I use EF 6.0.4 and .NET 6, and found a code which:

- gets a db context in a method
- executes some USP-s on the ctx, inside the USP-s there are some modifications in tables (SQL insert, update, etc.)
- then the method simple finishes - without calling ctx.SaveChanges()

What will happens? Without calling the SaveChanges all the modifications will be cancelled? or commited? What is the expected EF behaviour in this case?

To add some code sample:

```
public void CallUpdate()
{
  var ctx = Factory.CreateDbContext();
  ctx.Database.SetCommandTimeout(new TimeSpan(0,0,10,0));
  ctx.SomeEntities1.FromSqlRaw("EXEC myUsp1"); // insert into ... from ... etc
  ctx.SomeEntities2.FromSqlRaw("EXEC myUsp2"); // delete from ... etc
}
```

As far as I see the changes will be committed after some time. Seems not immediately when the method finishes. Maybe not. Hard to see when the changes are committed. My strong feeling that a reuse of a context might indicate an implicit commit, but the "reuse" time is not defined.

Or I'm completely wrong.

Any idea?

Comment: Also it seems that during the USP execution some table updates go live much more earlier than others...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that executing USP with a ctx does not require to call ctx.SaveChanges() to modify the table entities.

Comment: Correct, but it also means that any in-memory entity objects that _were_ modified or added won't be saved by EF, and if you do save them manually using a `PROCEDURE` then EF will be _unaware_ of that and still mark those entities as `EntityState.Modified`. This is why I think it's a bad idea to use a `PROCEDURE` which does DML (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE`) via your `DbContext` - I think it's better to keep things apart.